# What are the settings to execute job only once in Laravel Horizon?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-horizon

I'm a bit confuse about how to run the job only once, because when I set the parameter "tries" to 1 and the job fails, it execute one more time. If I set the tries parameter to 3, the job runs 4 times. And finally if I set to 0, the jobs run indefinitely. Below my settings in config/horizon.php:

```
'production' =
    'default' => [
            'connection'   => 'redis',
            'queue'        => [
                'default',
                'notifications',
                'dom'
            ],
            'balance'      => 'auto',
            'maxProcesses' => env('MAX_PROCESSES', 45),
            'timeout'      => 60,
            'tries'        => 1,
        ],
    ],
```

And below my settings in config/queue.php

```
'redis' => [
        'driver'      => 'redis',
        'connection'  => 'default',
        'queue'       => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

And other question, what setting dispatch the "has been attempted to many times or run too along"?

Comment: Is the job failing or is it timing out?

Comment: The problem with repeated jobs it's only when the job fails.  The other question about "has been attempted to many times" it's an curiosity.

Comment: Any ideia to help me to solve this problem @mtinsley ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set an attribute `$tries = 1` to the Job, and on the catch of possible errors, call `$this->fail()`;